# Localize the service

Tags: java, soap, internationalization

We have implemented soap service in java which is returning xml response to soap client. Currently we are supporting only English language.We want to support all language.

We have provide soap client API for accessing our service also.

As we want add support for transliteration support in our service so that it can support all language characters.

So i have below confusions,

1: Should i add support for transliteration at server side and send English response so that client 
   won't worry about transliteration process?

2: Should i add support for transliteration at client side so that it becomes client specific as per   his requirement?

Please let me know which approach should i use to implement transliteration  functionality in our application.

Comment: What data does the service provide? Could it be written to provide locale agnostic data, e.g. stock code/price? How many clients are there and do you have control over all of them?

Comment: What is your aim? Do you really want to transliterate something (that is change writing system to i.e. Latin) or translate (on the fly?) or just simply provide the **translations** to the client?